# Visual Studio Code Installed twice, how to uninstall completely?

Tags: visual-studio-code, uninstallation

1. *I installed Visual Studio Code 1.14.2 first. Then I installed Visual Studio Code 1.15.1(the 2nd Installation) again without uninstall the previous version (I forgot!)*. The 2nd Installation(the Visual Studio Code 1.15.1) still done successfully. The installed software shows the 2nd software(Visual Studio Code 1.15.1)
2. I uninstalled the 2nd Installation(Visual Studio Code 1.15.1). After uninstallation, I tried to install Visual Studio Code 1.15.1(The 2nd) again. But this installation process becomes wired: I don't need to install this software, the installation process did not execute. I can directly launch(open) the software without installing the software. Just like the portable version that it does not need installation. ** Visual Studio Code 1.15.1(the 2nd) runs normally**. When I launch(open) the software of Visual Studio Code 1.15.1

***Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features\the Installed Products list***

```
Visual Studio Code 1.15.1(the 2nd) is still not on this Installed Products list.
```

3. Any uninstall tool suggestion?

My computer is Windows 10.1 Pro upgraded from Win 8.1  My computer uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 before. Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to mention which OS you're using.

Comment: Windows 10.1 Pro (Chinese Traditional) upgraded from Win 8.1

Thank you very much!   _**Rob Lourens**_

Comment: You could remove the files from the hard drive then launch 'regedit' and find all instances of 'Visual Studio' and remove these.

Comment: I've removed old installations using this method before and most uninstalled do not remove all registry entries

Comment: I would use Regedit, just be careful and do not delete anything that you aren't 100% sure about.

Comment: @**SPlatten**:
as your instruction:
(a) The removal tool, REVO UNINSTALLER, can't work.
It can't detect/find the name of the software, therefore no way to remove it by removal tool.

(b) deleted files on HDD & launched 'regedit' to delete all instances of 'Visual Studio'

Comment: @**SPlatten**:

<!-- THE RESULT -->
  on (b), it still remains the same: I can directly launch(open) the software without installing the software.

  (c) It worked:
after uninstalled again, I tried to install Visual Studio Code version 1.5.3(Taiwan language version), _**it worked this way! DONE!**_   
I guess this version(Visual Studio Code 1.5.3) is further from the 1st version Visual Studio Code 1.14.2   So the inter-dependency or interuption are not hi w/ the 1st version ??!!(not sure)

(d) Could I ask (b): why I used regedit already, still not installing!

Comment: <!-- REFERENCE -->

Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed  
Resolving Installation Issues with Visual Studio 2017
http://rion.io/2017/02/17/resolving-installation-issues-with-visual-studio-2017/
Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller
https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

@**SPlatten**: Thank you very much. U R THE ONE
‧★,:*:‧\(￣▽￣)/‧:*‧°★*         _**SPlatten**_         ‧★,:*:‧\(￣▽￣)/‧:*‧°★*

Comment: Your very welcome!